# Error: Cannot convert array of data to (class)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm still rather new to JS and GAS and I'm afraid I don't understand arrays real well yet.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Prior to this script, I have another script that pulls information from a list into a spreadsheet that is formatted to look like an invoice. The user then makes changes to the invoice and saves that changes back again to the exact same line that the data was pulled from. This is simply a way of updating changes to the invoice in a user-friendly format.

When I run my script below, I get an error saying that it "Cannot convert"...a list of the data in the array..." to (class)"...the name of the file.

I'm afraid I don't know enough about array classes to solve this problem. I looked for other questions and answers to this same problem, but if I found one, I didn't understand it well enough to apply it to my situation.

The error is happening on line 133 (oh, so close to running the whole script).

```js
function overwriteInvoice() {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  
  
  
  //start change customer name into customer code
  var customerName = sheet.getRange('I2').getValue();
  var ccsheet = ss.getSheetByName("CustomerCodes");
  var lastRow = ccsheet.getLastRow();
  //check how many rows it found
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  var lookUp = ccsheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 3).getValues();
  for (nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {
    if (lookUp[nn][0] == customerName) {break}
  }
  var customerCode = lookUp[nn][1];
  //check customer code to make sure it is returning correct info.
  Logger.log("customerCode: " + customerCode);
  //end change customer name into customer code
  
  
  //start build array
  var arrayOfData = [];
  
  arrayOfData[0] = sheet.getRange('G2');//invoiceorquote
  arrayOfData[1] = sheet.getRange('C10');//invoicequote number
  arrayOfData[2] = sheet.getRange('C9');//date
  arrayOfData[3] = customerCode;//customer code DON'T CHANGE THIS
  arrayOfData[4] = sheet.getRange('I9');   //joblotcode         
  arrayOfData[5] = sheet.getRange('J27');//total
  arrayOfData[6] = sheet.getRange('L32');//invoice paid
  arrayOfData[7] = sheet.getRange('B30');//notes
  arrayOfData[8] = sheet.getRange('B13');//area13;
  arrayOfData[9] = sheet.getRange('D13');//description13;
  arrayOfData[10] = sheet.getRange('I13');//quantity13;
  arrayOfData[11] = sheet.getRange('J13');//units13;
  arrayOfData[12] = sheet.getRange('K13');//pricePerUnit13;
  arrayOfData[13] = sheet.getRange('L13');//subtotal13;
  arrayOfData[14] = sheet.getRange('B14');//area14;
  arrayOfData[15] = sheet.getRange('D14');//description14;
  arrayOfData[16] = sheet.getRange('I14');//quantity14;
  arrayOfData[17] = sheet.getRange('J14');//units14;
  arrayOfData[18] = sheet.getRange('K14');//pricePerUnit14;
  arrayOfData[19] = sheet.getRange('L14');//subtotal14;
  arrayOfData[20] = sheet.getRange('B15');//area15;
  arrayOfData[21] = sheet.getRange('D15');//description15;
  arrayOfData[22] = sheet.getRange('I15');//quantity15;
  arrayOfData[23] = sheet.getRange('J15');//units15 ;
  arrayOfData[24] = sheet.getRange('K15');//pricePerUnit15 ;
  arrayOfData[25] = sheet.getRange('L15');//subtotal15 ;
  arrayOfData[26] = sheet.getRange('B16');//area16 ;
  arrayOfData[27] = sheet.getRange('D16');//description16 ;
  arrayOfData[28] = sheet.getRange('I16');//quantity16 ;
  arrayOfData[29] = sheet.getRange('J16');//units16 ;
  arrayOfData[30] = sheet.getRange('K16');//pricePerUnit16 ;
  arrayOfData[31] = sheet.getRange('L16');//subtotal16 ;
  arrayOfData[32] = sheet.getRange('B17');//area17 ;
  arrayOfData[33] = sheet.getRange('D17');//description17 ;
  arrayOfData[34] = sheet.getRange('I17');//quantity17 ;
  arrayOfData[35] = sheet.getRange('J17');//units17 ;
  arrayOfData[36] = sheet.getRange('K17');//pricePerUnit17 ;
  arrayOfData[37] = sheet.getRange('L17');//subtotal17 ;
  arrayOfData[38] = sheet.getRange('B18');//area18 ;
  arrayOfData[39] = sheet.getRange('D18');//description18 ;
  arrayOfData[40] = sheet.getRange('I18');//quantity18 ;
  arrayOfData[41] = sheet.getRange('J18');//units18 ;
  arrayOfData[42] = sheet.getRange('K18');//pricePerUnit18 ;
  arrayOfData[43] = sheet.getRange('L18');//subtotal18 ;
  arrayOfData[44] = sheet.getRange('B19');//area19 ;
  arrayOfData[45] = sheet.getRange('D19');//description19 ;
  arrayOfData[46] = sheet.getRange('I19');//quantity19 ;
  arrayOfData[47] = sheet.getRange('J19');//units19 ;
  arrayOfData[48] = sheet.getRange('K19');//pricePerUnit19 ;
  arrayOfData[49] = sheet.getRange('L19');//subtotal19 ;
  arrayOfData[50] = sheet.getRange('B20');//area20 ;
  arrayOfData[51] = sheet.getRange('D20');//description20 ;
  arrayOfData[52] = sheet.getRange('I20');//quantity20 ;
  arrayOfData[53] = sheet.getRange('J20');//units20 ;
  arrayOfData[54] = sheet.getRange('K20');//pricePerUnit20 ;
  arrayOfData[55] = sheet.getRange('L20');//subtotal20 ;
  arrayOfData[56] = sheet.getRange('B21');//area21 ;
  arrayOfData[57] = sheet.getRange('D21');//description21 ;
  arrayOfData[58] = sheet.getRange('I21');//quantity21 ;
  arrayOfData[59] = sheet.getRange('J21');//units21 ;
  arrayOfData[60] = sheet.getRange('K21');//pricePerUnit21 ;
  arrayOfData[61] = sheet.getRange('L21');//subtotal21 ;
  arrayOfData[62] = sheet.getRange('B22');//area22 ;
  arrayOfData[63] = sheet.getRange('D22');//description22 ;
  arrayOfData[64] = sheet.getRange('I22');//quantity22 ;
  arrayOfData[65] = sheet.getRange('J22');//units22 ;
  arrayOfData[66] = sheet.getRange('K22');//pricePerUnit22 ;
  arrayOfData[67] = sheet.getRange('L22');//subtotal22 ;
  arrayOfData[68] = sheet.getRange('B23');//area23 ;
  arrayOfData[69] = sheet.getRange('D23');//description23 ;
  arrayOfData[70] = sheet.getRange('I23');//quantity23 ;
  arrayOfData[71] = sheet.getRange('J23');//units23 ;
  arrayOfData[72] = sheet.getRange('K23');//pricePerUnit23 ;
  arrayOfData[73] = sheet.getRange('L23');//subtotal23 ;
  arrayOfData[74] = sheet.getRange('B24');//area24 ;
  arrayOfData[75] = sheet.getRange('D24');//description24 ;
  arrayOfData[76] = sheet.getRange('I24');//quantity24 ;
  arrayOfData[77] = sheet.getRange('J24');//units24 ;
  arrayOfData[78] = sheet.getRange('K24');//pricePerUnit24 ;
  arrayOfData[79] = sheet.getRange('L24');//subtotal24 ;
  //end build array

  
  
  
  //start find correct row
  
  var searchFor = sheet.getRange("C10").getValue();
  var invoiceRecord = ss.getSheetByName("InvoiceRecord");
  var lastRow = invoiceRecord.getLastRow();
  //verify last row
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  //create an array of values to search
  var searchArea = invoiceRecord.getRange(4, 1, lastRow, 4).getValues();
  //start search the array
  for (jj=0; jj<searchArea.length; ++jj)  {
    if (searchArea[jj][1]==searchFor)  {break};
  }
  var copyToRow = searchArea[jj];
   
  //end find the correct row
  
  
  
  //ERROR!
  invoiceRecord.getRange(copyToRow, 1, 1, arrayOfData.length).setValues(arrayOfData);
  //ERROR!
  
  ui.alert('Invoice Changes Saved', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  
  
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

---

### Update

I am so frustrated by this problem that I decided to take a different tact to narrow down the cause. I removed the array entirely and assigned each value to a variable in order to see if the array is the problem. Apparently, it is not. The results when I run this code now say error: "Cannot convert NaN to (class). (line 140, file "OverwriteExistingInvoice")"

```js
function overwriteInvoice() {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  
  
  
  //start change customer name into customer code
  var customerName = sheet.getRange('I2').getValue();
  var ccsheet = ss.getSheetByName("CustomerCodes");
  var lastRow = ccsheet.getLastRow();
  //check how many rows it found
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  var lookUp = ccsheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-2, 3).getValues();
  
  var nn=0
  for (nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {
    if (lookUp[nn][0] == customerName) {break}
  }
  var customerCode = lookUp[nn][1];
  //check customer code to make sure it is returning correct info.
  Logger.log("customerCode: " + customerCode);
  //end change customer name into customer code
  
  
  //start build array

  
  var column0 = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();//invoiceorquote
  var column1 = sheet.getRange('C10').getValue();//invoicequote number
  var column2 = sheet.getRange('C9').getValue();//date
  var column3 = customerCode;//customer code DON'T CHANGE THIS
  var column4 = sheet.getRange('I9').getValue();   //joblotcode         
  var column5 = sheet.getRange('J27').getValue();//total
  var column6 = sheet.getRange('L32').getValue();//invoice paid
  var column7 = sheet.getRange('B30').getValue();//notes
  var column8 = sheet.getRange('B13').getValue();//area13;
  var column9 = sheet.getRange('D13').getValue();//description13;
  var column10 = sheet.getRange('I13').getValue();//quantity13;
  var column11 = sheet.getRange('J13').getValue();//units13;
  var column12 = sheet.getRange('K13').getValue();//pricePerUnit13;
  var column13 = sheet.getRange('L13').getValue();//subtotal13;
  var column14 = sheet.getRange('B14').getValue();//area14;
  var column15 = sheet.getRange('D14').getValue();//description14;
  var column16 = sheet.getRange('I14').getValue();//quantity14;
  var column17 = sheet.getRange('J14').getValue();//units14;
  var column18 = sheet.getRange('K14').getValue();//pricePerUnit14;
  var column19 = sheet.getRange('L14').getValue();//subtotal14;
  var column20 = sheet.getRange('B15').getValue();//area15;
  var column21 = sheet.getRange('D15').getValue();//description15;
  var column22 = sheet.getRange('I15').getValue();//quantity15;
  var column23 = sheet.getRange('J15').getValue();//units15 ;
  var column24 = sheet.getRange('K15').getValue();//pricePerUnit15 ;
  var column25 = sheet.getRange('L15').getValue();//subtotal15 ;
  var column26 = sheet.getRange('B16').getValue();//area16 ;
  var column27 = sheet.getRange('D16').getValue();//description16 ;
  var column28 = sheet.getRange('I16').getValue();//quantity16 ;
  var column29 = sheet.getRange('J16').getValue();//units16 ;
  var column30 = sheet.getRange('K16').getValue();//pricePerUnit16 ;
  var column31 = sheet.getRange('L16').getValue();//subtotal16 ;
  var column32 = sheet.getRange('B17').getValue();//area17 ;
  var column33 = sheet.getRange('D17').getValue();//description17 ;
  var column34 = sheet.getRange('I17').getValue();//quantity17 ;
  var column35 = sheet.getRange('J17').getValue();//units17 ;
  var column36 = sheet.getRange('K17').getValue();//pricePerUnit17 ;
  var column37 = sheet.getRange('L17').getValue();//subtotal17 ;
  var column38 = sheet.getRange('B18').getValue();//area18 ;
  var column39 = sheet.getRange('D18').getValue();//description18 ;
  var column40 = sheet.getRange('I18').getValue();//quantity18 ;
  var column41 = sheet.getRange('J18').getValue();//units18 ;
  var column42 = sheet.getRange('K18').getValue();//pricePerUnit18 ;
  var column43 = sheet.getRange('L18').getValue();//subtotal18 ;
  var column44 = sheet.getRange('B19').getValue();//area19 ;
  var column45 = sheet.getRange('D19').getValue();//description19 ;
  var column46 = sheet.getRange('I19').getValue();//quantity19 ;
  var column47 = sheet.getRange('J19').getValue();//units19 ;
  var column48 = sheet.getRange('K19').getValue();//pricePerUnit19 ;
  var column49 = sheet.getRange('L19').getValue();//subtotal19 ;
  var column50 = sheet.getRange('B20').getValue();//area20 ;
  var column51 = sheet.getRange('D20').getValue();//description20 ;
  var column52 = sheet.getRange('I20').getValue();//quantity20 ;
  var column53 = sheet.getRange('J20').getValue();//units20 ;
  var column54 = sheet.getRange('K20').getValue();//pricePerUnit20 ;
  var column55 = sheet.getRange('L20').getValue();//subtotal20 ;
  var column56 = sheet.getRange('B21').getValue();//area21 ;
  var column57 = sheet.getRange('D21').getValue();//description21 ;
  var column58 = sheet.getRange('I21').getValue();//quantity21 ;
  var column59 = sheet.getRange('J21').getValue();//units21 ;
  var column60 = sheet.getRange('K21').getValue();//pricePerUnit21 ;
  var column61 = sheet.getRange('L21').getValue();//subtotal21 ;
  var column62 = sheet.getRange('B22').getValue();//area22 ;
  var column63 = sheet.getRange('D22').getValue();//description22 ;
  var column64 = sheet.getRange('I22').getValue();//quantity22 ;
  var column65 = sheet.getRange('J22').getValue();//units22 ;
  var column66 = sheet.getRange('K22').getValue();//pricePerUnit22 ;
  var column67 = sheet.getRange('L22').getValue();//subtotal22 ;
  var column68 = sheet.getRange('B23').getValue();//area23 ;
  var column69 = sheet.getRange('D23').getValue();//description23 ;
  var column70 = sheet.getRange('I23').getValue();//quantity23 ;
  var column71 = sheet.getRange('J23').getValue();//units23 ;
  var column72 = sheet.getRange('K23').getValue();//pricePerUnit23 ;
  var column73 = sheet.getRange('L23').getValue();//subtotal23 ;
  var column74 = sheet.getRange('B24').getValue();//area24 ;
  var column75 = sheet.getRange('D24').getValue();//description24 ;
  var column76 = sheet.getRange('I24').getValue();//quantity24 ;
  var column77 = sheet.getRange('J24').getValue();//units24 ;
  var column78 = sheet.getRange('K24').getValue();//pricePerUnit24 ;
  var column79 = sheet.getRange('L24').getValue();//subtotal24 ;
  //end build array

  
  
  
  //start find correct row
  
  var searchFor = sheet.getRange("C10").getValue();
  var invoiceRecord = ss.getSheetByName("InvoiceRecord");
  var lastRow = invoiceRecord.getLastRow();
  //verify last row
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  //create an array of values to search
  var searchArea = invoiceRecord.getRange(4, 1, lastRow, 4).getValues();
  //start search the array
  var jj=0
  for (jj=0; jj<searchArea.length; ++jj)  {
    if (searchArea[jj][1]==searchFor)  {break};
  }
  
  Logger.log('jj value: ' + jj);
  
  var copyToRow = searchArea[jj];
  
  Logger.log('copyToRow: ' + copyToRow);
  //end find correct row
  
    
  //start copy over same entry
 //error on next line 
   invoiceRecord.getRange(copyToRow-1, 1).setValue(column0);
 //error on above line 
  ui.alert('Invoice Changes Saved', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  
  
}
```

I really appreciate all the help thus far. I am about to tear my hair out!

**UPDATE**

This is the code that finally worked correctly.

```js
function overwriteInvoice() {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  
  
  
  //start change customer name into customer code
  var customerName = sheet.getRange('I2').getValue();
  var ccsheet = ss.getSheetByName("CustomerCodes");
  var lastRow = ccsheet.getLastRow();
  //check how many rows it found
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  var lookUp = ccsheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-2, 3).getValues();
  
  var nn=0
  for (nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {
    if (lookUp[nn][0] == customerName) {break}
  }
  var customerCode = lookUp[nn][1];
  //check customer code to make sure it is returning correct info.
  Logger.log("customerCode: " + customerCode);
  //end change customer name into customer code
  
  
  //start build array
  var arrayOfData = [];

  
  arrayOfData[0] = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();//invoiceorquote
  arrayOfData[1] = sheet.getRange('C10').getValue();//invoicequote number
  arrayOfData[2] = sheet.getRange('C9').getValue();//date
  arrayOfData[3] = customerCode;//customer code DON'T CHANGE THIS
  arrayOfData[4] = sheet.getRange('I9').getValue();   //joblotcode         
  arrayOfData[5] = sheet.getRange('J27').getValue();//total
  arrayOfData[6] = sheet.getRange('L32').getValue();//invoice paid
  arrayOfData[7] = sheet.getRange('B30').getValue();//notes
  arrayOfData[8] = sheet.getRange('B13').getValue();//area13;
  arrayOfData[9] = sheet.getRange('D13').getValue();//description13;
  arrayOfData[10] = sheet.getRange('I13').getValue();//quantity13;
  arrayOfData[11] = sheet.getRange('J13').getValue();//units13;
  arrayOfData[12] = sheet.getRange('K13').getValue();//pricePerUnit13;
  arrayOfData[13] = sheet.getRange('L13').getValue();//subtotal13;
  arrayOfData[14] = sheet.getRange('B14').getValue();//area14;
  arrayOfData[15] = sheet.getRange('D14').getValue();//description14;
  arrayOfData[16] = sheet.getRange('I14').getValue();//quantity14;
  arrayOfData[17] = sheet.getRange('J14').getValue();//units14;
  arrayOfData[18] = sheet.getRange('K14').getValue();//pricePerUnit14;
  arrayOfData[19] = sheet.getRange('L14').getValue();//subtotal14;
  arrayOfData[20] = sheet.getRange('B15').getValue();//area15;
  arrayOfData[21] = sheet.getRange('D15').getValue();//description15;
  arrayOfData[22] = sheet.getRange('I15').getValue();//quantity15;
  arrayOfData[23] = sheet.getRange('J15').getValue();//units15 ;
  arrayOfData[24] = sheet.getRange('K15').getValue();//pricePerUnit15 ;
  arrayOfData[25] = sheet.getRange('L15').getValue();//subtotal15 ;
  arrayOfData[26] = sheet.getRange('B16').getValue();//area16 ;
  arrayOfData[27] = sheet.getRange('D16').getValue();//description16 ;
  arrayOfData[28] = sheet.getRange('I16').getValue();//quantity16 ;
  arrayOfData[29] = sheet.getRange('J16').getValue();//units16 ;
  arrayOfData[30] = sheet.getRange('K16').getValue();//pricePerUnit16 ;
  arrayOfData[31] = sheet.getRange('L16').getValue();//subtotal16 ;
  arrayOfData[32] = sheet.getRange('B17').getValue();//area17 ;
  arrayOfData[33] = sheet.getRange('D17').getValue();//description17 ;
  arrayOfData[34] = sheet.getRange('I17').getValue();//quantity17 ;
  arrayOfData[35] = sheet.getRange('J17').getValue();//units17 ;
  arrayOfData[36] = sheet.getRange('K17').getValue();//pricePerUnit17 ;
  arrayOfData[37] = sheet.getRange('L17').getValue();//subtotal17 ;
  arrayOfData[38] = sheet.getRange('B18').getValue();//area18 ;
  arrayOfData[39] = sheet.getRange('D18').getValue();//description18 ;
  arrayOfData[40] = sheet.getRange('I18').getValue();//quantity18 ;
  arrayOfData[41] = sheet.getRange('J18').getValue();//units18 ;
  arrayOfData[42] = sheet.getRange('K18').getValue();//pricePerUnit18 ;
  arrayOfData[43] = sheet.getRange('L18').getValue();//subtotal18 ;
  arrayOfData[44] = sheet.getRange('B19').getValue();//area19 ;
  arrayOfData[45] = sheet.getRange('D19').getValue();//description19 ;
  arrayOfData[46] = sheet.getRange('I19').getValue();//quantity19 ;
  arrayOfData[47] = sheet.getRange('J19').getValue();//units19 ;
  arrayOfData[48] = sheet.getRange('K19').getValue();//pricePerUnit19 ;
  arrayOfData[49] = sheet.getRange('L19').getValue();//subtotal19 ;
  arrayOfData[50] = sheet.getRange('B20').getValue();//area20 ;
  arrayOfData[51] = sheet.getRange('D20').getValue();//description20 ;
  arrayOfData[52] = sheet.getRange('I20').getValue();//quantity20 ;
  arrayOfData[53] = sheet.getRange('J20').getValue();//units20 ;
  arrayOfData[54] = sheet.getRange('K20').getValue();//pricePerUnit20 ;
  arrayOfData[55] = sheet.getRange('L20').getValue();//subtotal20 ;
  arrayOfData[56] = sheet.getRange('B21').getValue();//area21 ;
  arrayOfData[57] = sheet.getRange('D21').getValue();//description21 ;
  arrayOfData[58] = sheet.getRange('I21').getValue();//quantity21 ;
  arrayOfData[59] = sheet.getRange('J21').getValue();//units21 ;
  arrayOfData[60] = sheet.getRange('K21').getValue();//pricePerUnit21 ;
  arrayOfData[61] = sheet.getRange('L21').getValue();//subtotal21 ;
  arrayOfData[62] = sheet.getRange('B22').getValue();//area22 ;
  arrayOfData[63] = sheet.getRange('D22').getValue();//description22 ;
  arrayOfData[64] = sheet.getRange('I22').getValue();//quantity22 ;
  arrayOfData[65] = sheet.getRange('J22').getValue();//units22 ;
  arrayOfData[66] = sheet.getRange('K22').getValue();//pricePerUnit22 ;
  arrayOfData[67] = sheet.getRange('L22').getValue();//subtotal22 ;
  arrayOfData[68] = sheet.getRange('B23').getValue();//area23 ;
  arrayOfData[69] = sheet.getRange('D23').getValue();//description23 ;
  arrayOfData[70] = sheet.getRange('I23').getValue();//quantity23 ;
  arrayOfData[71] = sheet.getRange('J23').getValue();//units23 ;
  arrayOfData[72] = sheet.getRange('K23').getValue();//pricePerUnit23 ;
  arrayOfData[73] = sheet.getRange('L23').getValue();//subtotal23 ;
  arrayOfData[74] = sheet.getRange('B24').getValue();//area24 ;
  arrayOfData[75] = sheet.getRange('D24').getValue();//description24 ;
  arrayOfData[76] = sheet.getRange('I24').getValue();//quantity24 ;
  arrayOfData[77] = sheet.getRange('J24').getValue();//units24 ;
  arrayOfData[78] = sheet.getRange('K24').getValue();//pricePerUnit24 ;
  arrayOfData[79] = sheet.getRange('L24').getValue();//subtotal24 ;
  //end build array

  
  
  
  //start find correct row
  
  var searchFor = sheet.getRange("C10").getValue();
  var invoiceRecord = ss.getSheetByName("InvoiceRecord");
  var lastRow = invoiceRecord.getLastRow();
  //verify last row
  Logger.log("lastRow: " + lastRow);
  //create an array of values to search
  var searchArea = invoiceRecord.getRange(4, 1, lastRow, 4).getValues();
  //start search the array
  var jj=0
  for (jj=0; jj<searchArea.length; ++jj)  {
    if (searchArea[jj][1]==searchFor)  {break};
  }
  
  Logger.log('jj value: ' + jj);
  
  var copyToRow = jj+4;
  
  Logger.log('copyToRow: ' + copyToRow);
  //end find correct row
    
  //start copy over the same entry
  
  var outerArray = [];
  outerArray.push(arrayOfData);
  
  invoiceRecord.getRange(copyToRow, 1, 1, 80).setValues(outerArray);
 
      
  
  ui.alert('Invoice Changes Saved', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  
  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to the error, but there are some minor things you should change.  `var lookUp = ccsheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 3).getValues();`  Subtract 1 from the lastRow:  `lastRow - 1`.  Otherwise, the last inner array will be blank values.  You are starting on row 2, so the number of rows to get is not the same as the number of rows in the spreadsheet.  Declare `nn` outside of the loop but before the `for` loop:  `var nn = 0;  for (nn=0; nn<lookUp.length; ++nn) {`  You are using `nn` outside of the loop, so it needs to be declared outside of the loop, but currently it's a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `getValue()` method to all of the lines with:

```
arrayOfData[x] = sheet.getRange('XX');//What to get
```

Right now, a range object is being put into the array, and not a value.

Should be:

```
arrayOfData[x] = sheet.getRange('XX').getValue();//Note
```

Create an outer array, and put `arrayOfData` into it:

```
var outerArray = [];
outerArray.push(arrayOfData);

//getRange(Start row, start column, number of rows, number of columns)
invoiceRecord.getRange(copyToRow, 1, outerArray.length, outerArray[0].length)
  .setValues(outerArray);
```

The `setValues()` method must have a two dimensional array.  If this is for just one row of data, then there will only be one inner array.

Comment: Ah, that is what I didn't understand. It is only a single row of data so I didn't think I needed a two-dimensional array. Thank you so much. This solves my problem.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I made the changes you suggested but I still get the error, "Cannot convert [then it list the items in the array] to {class}" on the same line. Anyting else that could cause that error?

Comment: Add the `getValue()` method to all the lines that are populating the array.  Right now, an object is being put into each array element, and not a value.  See updated answer.

Comment: I made that change as well. Same error. Any other suggestions?  Thanks for sticking with this one. You have been a great help.

Comment: You need to print some values to the log, and find out exactly what is going on.  Put a `Logger.log('arrayOfData.length: ' + arrayOfData.length);` statement right before the line that is setting the values, run the code, and VIEW the LOGS.  For testing purposes, you don't need to set the values, so either put in a `return;` statement to stop the code before the line that sets the values, or put in a non-existent function name:  `end()`.  That will stop the code at that line with an error msg, but you can still view the Logs.  Also log the `arrayOfData[0].length`.  Let me know what you find.

Comment: Here is the log results from doing as you suggested.

Comment: [16-03-10 16:54:14:144 MST] lastRow: 509
[16-03-10 16:54:14:368 MST] customerCode: MR
[16-03-10 16:54:20:360 MST] lastRow: 23
[16-03-10 16:54:20:449 MST] arrayOfData.length: 80
[16-03-10 16:54:20:450 MST] arrayOfData[0].length: 7

Comment: FYI...those logs are returning valid information. There are 7 characters in item 1 [0] and there are 80 cells across the row. The last cell is empty. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The data array of values to set, can be a two dimensional array, and still not work if every single inner array is not the same length.  You can't have even a single inner array that is a different length than all the other inner arrays.  You may need to loop through all the data in the array, and check to see what it's structure is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. The array is 80 cells of data. Every cell has a different character count. What am I not seeing about the length of the inner array? Sorry, I'm just learning about this stuff and I'm struggling to teach myself and/or rely on the grace of knowledgeable people like you to teach me.

Comment: In this case, the length settings should not be the number of characters in a value.  The length property can be used on a string, to get the number of characters in a string, and the length property can also be used on an array to get the number of ELEMENTS in an array.  In this case, the length settings needed, are the number of inner arrays in the outer array, and the number of cell values in each inner array.  Each inner array represents a row, every value (Element) in the inner array represents a cell value.  So, the character count should NOT be used, if that is what you are using.

Comment: So, how do I call the proper lengths, or do I just enter them manually? The way I called the lengths in the examples above is the only way I know how to do it.

Comment: You should set the lengths like this:  `getRange(copyToRow, 1, outerArray.length, outerArray[0].length)`  Where outerArray is the array of data that will be used in the `setValues()` method.  `getRange(copyToRow, 1, outerArray.length, outerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray)`

Comment: This is still not working. I think I am chasing the wrong problem. I will edit the code in the question above to reflect a new tact I am trying to find the problem.

Comment: Turns out, all your suggestions were a part of the answer, and the reason they did not work was because one of my variables was reading as a string instead of a number. Once I fixed that, the answers you originally provided worked perfect! Thanks!